# Formatting values as currency on Google Sheets pie chart labels

Tags: google-sheets

I've created a pie chart in Google Sheets and used the values as labels. However, they are showing up with a lot of decimals as they are a sum of the referenced columns.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_8DQTa9aXGjvd7twL6RZMcFyqxa4Sg7eVTcD2wDXH2A/edit?usp=sharing

How do I format them as currency within the pie chart?

[image]

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Shared a copy of sheet

Answer (score 0):

You need an intermediary table with values aggrigated by category

> Paste this formula to get intermediary table

```
=ArrayFormula({C1,B1;  UNIQUE(C2:C), IF(UNIQUE(C2:C)="",,SUMIF(C2:C,"="&UNIQUE(C2:C),B2:B))})
```

[image]

- Duplicate you current chart and change the range to the intermediary table `H3:I1000` in this case
- and disable Aggregate in the chart editor > Setup > Lable >  - Aggregate

[image]

Comment: This didn't work. Shared copy of sheet so you can see.

Comment: @eComEvo I did update the answer take a look.

Answer (score 0):

internal chart settings are not so versatile so you will need to do it like this:

```
=QUERY(B2:C, "select C,sum(B) where C is not null group by C order by sum(B) desc label sum(B)''")
```

[image]

[image]